# StanfordNLP training iteration for CRF classifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I know its a simple question. But I just want to make sure. Are all the samples from training dataset used in each iterations in CRF classifier?

Comment: Yes, al the samples are used to train the model, you should have a hold-out set to evaluate the model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes during the training process all training examples are used during each iteration.